# Converting datatype of @biServer.variables in OBIEE 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee

I'm using one of the repository variables for extracting year, here is the SQL code:

```
SELECT "Time_D"."Year"
  FROM "Order D"
 WHERE "Time_D"."Year" <= '@{biServer.variables[' Current_year ']}'
   AND "Time_D"."Year" >= '2020'
 ORDER BY "Time_D"."Year" DESC
```

But the result is:

```
2021,00
2020,00
```

How can I remove ',00' in front of the year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Khm, it's actually *behind* it.

As far as Oracle itself is concerned, you could try with `substr` or `regexp_substr`, e.g.

```
select substr("Time_D"."Year", 1, 4)         as year_1,
       regexp_substr("Time_D"."Year", '\d+') as year_2
from ...
```

Or, if that's an *item* in OBIEE, set its format mask (to remove decimals).

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to data types. If your output is of a numerical type, then by default you will have it with a decimal precision. As in 2021,00.

"2021" is a string, not a number. So if your output is a number then you just need to format the result  as "0 decimals".

That said - WHERE do you write that SQL?! In a direct database request?